# Is translation of a closed set by a compact set is closed?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $E$ be a normed vector space over $\mathbb R$, $A, B \subset E$ disjoint nonempty convex subsets, $A$ closed and $B$ compact.

In the proof of Theorem 1.7 of Brezis's *Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations*, he says, without proof, $C := A - B = \{ x - y \mid x \in A, y \in B \}$ is also convex and closed.

I can show that $C$ is convex. Although I am sure that $C$ is closed by *drawing* the situation, I do not give any proof for it.

Since $C = \bigcup_{x \in A} (x - B) = \bigcup_{y \in B} (A - y)$, it suffices to pick up finitely many $x_i \in A$ (or finitely many $y_j \in B$) so that $C = \bigcup_{i} (x_i - B)$ (or $= \bigcup_{j} (A - y_j)$), so that $C$ is now the union of finitely many closed sets.

I think I have to construct an open cover of the compact set $B$ in order to pick up finitely many open sets, which in turn are used to find $x_i$ or $y_j$. But I do not come up with such an open cover, nor other methods to proving the statement.

How to show that $C$ is actually closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to prove this is using sequences.  Suppose $(c_n)$ is a sequence in $C$ converging to some point $x\in E$.  For each $n$, we can write $c_n=a_n-b_n$ where $a_n\in A$ and $b_n\in B$.  Since $B$ is compact, we can pass to a subsequence and assume that $(b_n)$ converges to some $b\in B$.  But now since $c_n\to x$ and $b_n\to b$, $a_n=b_n+c_n$ must converge to $b+x$.  Since $A$ is closed, this means $b+x\in A$.  Thus $x=(b+x)-b\in C$, as desired.

Comment: right you are, should read more carefully (comment withdrawn).

Comment: Thanks! But I do not understand what "we can pass to a subsequence and assume ..." does mean. Of course, it has a convergent subsequence, and so does $\{ c_n \}$; hence $C$ is compact, which is closed. But why can I assume $\{ b_n \}$ itself converges?

Comment: "Pass to a subsequence" means we replace all our sequences with the corresponding subsequence.  So we pick a subsequence of $(b_n)$ that converges, and replace $(b_n)$ with that subsequence, and $(c_n)$ with its corresponding subsequence.